# Multiple Microphone Recording

Tags: matlab, audio, avaudiorecorder, usbserial, recorder

I'm trying to record from three microphones simultaneously for microphone array research. I have three USB Microphones connected to my Macbook air via a USB hub. In the Audio MIDI I have them as an aggregate device.

Matlab isn't recognizing them, and is still just recording from the internal microphone in the computer. What do I add to:

```
recobj1 = audiorecorder (22500,16,2);
disp ('recording started')
record(recobj1,5);
recordblocking(recobj1,5);

y = getaudiodata(recobj1);
wavwrite(y,22500,16)
```

to get Matlab to record from the USB Mic?

Comment: Side note: Title of your post is strange... I'm not sure if matlab have special meaning of "serial port" (I've never seen "serial port" used in relation to microphones). I'd recommend changing title to something that relates to "recording from multiple microphones".

Comment: okay! was looking at the 'record' fn and it was mentioning serial ports. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/record.html -

Comment: try the overload of `audiorecorder` that takes a 4th parameter called ID. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiorecorder.html